Acceptable format of dates in bibliographies
Is 1995.3 an acceptable format for March 1995 in English language bibliographies?

Are you using any particular style guide (Chicago, MLA, etc) - many have particular date formats. And if you're using author-date references (Smith, 2024) then there is a specific format for that in each style guide. In general "1995.3" is not very clear and most would prefer a written month, but it's ultimately a matter of opinion where the editor or teacher gets to choose. And it's important to be consistent.

Never seen that before - I would have no idea what it meant. it looks like a misprint for 1995 Q3, and 1995.6 would look like a misprint for 1995-6.

Thanks for your comments. I was merely curious as to whether anyone might say that they have seen or used that format before. I have been given a series of bibliographies to edit that were translated into English from Japanese. The client generally prefers that I keep the translation as close to the Japanese as possible and wants to leave that format as is, but I am arguing that I have never seen it used in English and can't find any style guide that recommends it.

I’d suggest you add that background to your question. And the question might be better suited to one of our sister SE sites like “Writing.”
